# Getting exit code from curl in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, curl

I want to take the output of `simple.sh`, a script from the internet and check its exit code.  I on OSX

```
#!/bin/bash
$(curl -s http://127.0.0.1:8000/simple.sh)
if [ -z "$?" ]; then
    echo "Good"
    exit 0
else
    echo "Bad"
    exit 1
fi
```

simple.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
exit 0
```

The problem I am getting is:

```
./test.sh: line 2: #!/bin/bash: No such file or directory
Bad
```

Comment: Try adding the full path to `curl`, i.e. the output from `type curl`. Probably a path issue.

Comment: try `eval "$(curl ...)"`

Comment: @datUser Same problem still comes up.

Comment: @Jonas Always returns "Good" no matter what the exit code from simple.sh is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say it's elegant, but this is the way I would do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -s http://127.0.0.1:8000/simple.sh | /bin/bash -s >/dev/null 2>&1
rc=$?
if [ -z "$rc" ]
then
    echo "Good"
    exit 0
else
    echo "Bad"
    exit 1
fi
```

Seems to me, the way you are doing it is similar to executing a here-file inside the *$( ... )* construct. Never tried that, not sure bash works that way.

Letting curl echo the contents of the file and piping it to bash accounts for the text output of the curl command and allows bash to execute it.

I'll bet that, if you try this, you will get the same results:

```
$( cat /[path]/simple.sh ); echo $?
```

Comment: I tested your script but as mentioned in another answer I had to change the if condition to `[ $? -eq 0 ]` and removed the unneeded rc variable.

Comment: It's debatable if rc=$? is actually necessary in this scenario. I do it out of habit, as many things I do actually _do_ need it.

Comment: I did the same as @user174174 and it works as expected!

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is right, but you seem to have defined a wrong conditional for checking the return code with `[ -z "$?" ]` which checks if the return code string is *empty* or not. Irrespective of the result of the `curl` output, your `$?` will carry a value which means, you'll never assert the `if` condition of your script. You probably need to check the return code that `curl` returns directly in your script

```
$(curl -s http://127.0.0.1:8000/simple.sh)
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
```

or even more tersely written without the `test` operator to allow the return code to be directly used in the `if` condition

```
if curl -s http://127.0.0.1:8000/simple.sh 2>&1 >/dev/null; then
```

Comment: `if curl ...; then` is true if curl fetches the web resource without error`if $(curl ...); then` is the same as `$(curl ...); if [ $? -eq 0]; then` and is true if executing the tokens in the content of the web resource as a (simple) command does not cause any error. In the Q the first token received is apparently `!#/bin/bash` and executing that does normally cause an error.

Comment: @Inian The first option you presented results in the same error.
The second option unconditionally results in "Good"